# Accessing a tuple element from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I've been making a little program in Python and the logic seems to work fine up until the final step where it retrieves the result. Codewise, it's similiar to this:

```
...
list1 = [(string,string,int),(string,string,int)...]
print(list1[0[0]])
```

This throws up a `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` error and I'm struggling to figure out why. Surely this is only meant to print index 0 of the list (tuple 1) and then index 0 of that (the string)? How would I go about getting this value out the list?

Comment: it is a simple type I guess.... you want:  print(list1[0][0])

Comment: ```0[0]``` has no sense, you can't subscript an integer. Just do ```list1[0][0]```. ```list1[0]``` will give you the tuple.

Comment: Is that the correct formatting, I feel really stupid now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with your formatting:
update `print` statement.

```
list1 = [(string,string,int),(string,string,int)...]
print(list1[0][0])
```

`[0[0]]` - wrong format to access a tuple element
`[0][0]` - correct format for accessing the first element of the first tuple.

Comment: list1 = [(string,string,int),(string,string,int)...]; first_ele= [ele[0] for ele in list1]; print(first_ele); prints first element in each tuples in list1.